# How to find point (lat, lng) inside a polygon with h3-js?

Tags: javascript, h3

I have a polygon created with `polyfill`, is it possible to know if the `point = [lat, lng]` is in that polygon (using only h3-js)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, though there's simplification involved - `polyfill` returns cells whose centers fall within the polygon, so you'll have cases at the edges of the polygon where specific points near the edge will be incorrectly included or excluded from the polygon. The tradeoff is that the inclusion check should be much faster than a traditional point-in-poly algorithm, and the code is simpler:

```js
// Create a set of H3 indexes representing the polygon. Using a finer
// value for H3_RES will give you better fidelity to the original 
// polygon, at the cost of more memory usage 
const polygonSet = new Set(h3.polyfill(myPolygon, H3_RES));

// Check whether a given point is in the polygon
function isPointInPoly(point) {
  const h3Index = h3.geoToH3(point.lat, point.lng, H3_RES);
  return polygonSet.has(h3Index);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by "finer value for H3_RES"? A higher value? Could you please share with me the docs related with H3_RES?

Comment: `H3_RES` was just some constant I was using for the H3 resolution argument. The range is 0-15, a higher number is a finer resolution.